# Making a variable conditionally global

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

Suppose that I'm required to run a function with a loop in it until I meet a condition.  For the function to work right, I'm only allowed to return one value in the function, but once the condition clears, I want to bring some of the calculations I performed into the global scope.  I'm not allowed to use the return command to do this, so I decided to globalize the variables *in post*.  This raises a warning, but seems to work alright.  Is this the best way to do things?

Here's an example:

```
def check_cond(x,cond):
    return (x - cond,3)

def loop(x,func):
    relevant_value = 0
    while x > 0:
        local_expensive_calculation = 1 #use your imagination
        x = func(x,local_expensive_calculation)[0]
        relevant_value += func(x,local_expensive_calculation)[1]
        if x == 0:
            global local_expensive_calculation
    return relevant_value

x = 4
loop(x,check_cond)

#then do stuff with local_expensive_calculation, which is now global
```

Comment: Can't you just return an object, like a tuple, that contains multiple values? Also, "I'm only allowed to return one value in the function..." seems to contradict "I'm not allowed to use the return command".

Comment: Well, I'm using the newton function from scipy to do this.  It requires that function you use inside it only returns one float, no tuples allowed.  As for my contradiction, I'm referring to the use of the return *beyond* what I'm allowed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be slightly abusing the system but you can set your variable as an attribute of the function, and then access it later through that namespace:

```
def check_cond(x,cond):
    return (x - cond,3)

def loop(x,func):
    relevant_value = 0
    while x > 0:
        local_expensive_calculation = 1 #use your imagination
        x = func(x,local_expensive_calculation)[0]
        relevant_value += func(x,local_expensive_calculation)[1]
        if x == 0:
            loop.local_expensive_calculation = local_expensive_calculation
    return relevant_value

x = 4
loop(x,check_cond)

print loop.local_expensive_calculation
```

Comment: This certainly works, and doesn't raises any errors, so I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely insist on having it as a global, one way you can do that is by changing the line:

```
global local_expensive_calculation
```

to:

```
globals()['local_expensive_calculation'] = local_expensive_calculation
```

It makes your SyntaxWarning disappear.

I don't know much about the context and it appears you want a Python 2.7 answer (Python 3.?) has `nonlocal`.

Bear in mind that the [while statement can also have a `else` clause](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement)

You can write:

```
while x>0:
    # do calculation and stuff
else:
    # make calculation result global
```

PS: There's a typo in your assignment to `x`: (`calcuation` --> `calculation`)